# Why did Python choose to use None instead of null?

Tags: python

Python seems to be created to be a fast, minimal language for getting stuff done. While I love Python, one thing has never made sense to me. Why name a null entity `None` rather than `Null` or even `null`? Save a character for free! Does anyone know why this road was taken in Python?

Comment: On the face of it this question is unanswerable, but I've been surprised at the number of obscure design decisions that have been documented by Guido. I'm not voting to close (yet).

Comment: `Save a character for free!`, this was never a Python Philosophy. Else we would have ended up with APL instead of Python

Comment: This is a legitimate and even good question. Why do you downvote?

Comment: @Abhijit, it doesn't make sense anyway since `None` and `Null` are both 4 characters.

Comment: Becaause the question is pointless, off topic and of zero interest

Comment: @thg435, no it's not a good question - it's just an arbitrary bit of trivia, and most answers are going to be speculative anyway.

Comment: This is a legitimate question but cannot be answered in a reasonable way. I agree with closing the question but rather disagree with the downvote.

Comment: @MarkRansom: a good answer to this would be a link to GvR's explanations which I believe to exist somewhere in comp.lang.python archives.

Comment: @thg435, that's why I said "most". See also my first comment. The problem is that even a good answer isn't going to do much more than satisfy someone's curiosity, and that makes me question its value. Still note that I never voted to close.

Comment: The implication here is that Python is somehow defective for not using `null` like every other language. Besides the fact that many of those other languages were invented long after Python, if you look at the other popular languages, there's a huge variety of different names for this and similar concepts—`undefined`, `nil`, `nullptr`, `nothing`, etc. (even ignoring case variations). Why is `null` better than any of these other choices, other than, maybe, because it's what the OP's first language used? (I'm ignoring the silly "save a character" bit, given that `not 4 < 4`…)

Comment: I would argue that the difference is in usage. `null` in Java, for instance, indicates an object that doesn't have any value. This is, in my opinion, subtly different to `None`, which implies there was no value returned. This is important as Python doesn't type functions, so we can't have `void` functions. 'What value was returned?' can be answered with 'a null value' or 'none was returned'.

Comment: FYI, Guido's own blog post talks about this: http://python-history.blogspot.fi/2013/11/story-of-none-true-false.html and the gist is in this paragraph: ``In the end we decided that there was no downside to making None a keyword (there is no code that actually assigns to it) and it might make some code a tiny bit faster, or catch rare typos. There was still a one-time cost to the developer community (changes to the parser and documentation) but this was small enough that we din't hesitate very long.``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a philosophical question: you're asking "why?".

Nonetheless, here's one answer: Python strives to be legible even for people who do not understand the language. This line:

```
if foo is None:
```

Reads better than this one:

```
if (foo == null) {
```

In normal English grammar, "null" isn't a *thing*. It's an adjective, not a noun. "None" is a noun, which is how you use it in computer science.

Comment: Interesting. When describing code to coworkers, I've always said "A is failing because B _is_ null." I don't understand why we couldn't have `foo is Null`, it reads the same way or, arguably, better. Saying that "foo is None" seems strange, to me. Even when discussing Python code, I would use the word "null" to describe something with the value of `None`.

Comment: I would like to disagree here. COBOL was written to be more english like but when initializing Pointers it uses NULL rather any grammatically correct word. [Initializing Pointers Using the NULL Figurative Constant](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.iseries.pgmgd.doc%2Fc0925405286.htm)